# Animating pendulums in Jupyter notebook using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook, physics

UPDATE: It is an issue getting the animation to compile and run within Jupyter itself. As an easy workaround, I am just going to compile animations in IDLE, save them as a gif, then import them into my notebook via markdown.

I am trying to animate different pendulum systems within a Jupyter notebook. I am solving the differential equations for the systems, then creating a list of angle values to plot versus time (that part is easy ;). I have created a dummy list of theta values to simplify things for this post. The first goal is to get a line with a fixed point to sway back and forth (like a pendulum), eventually adding a mass on the end of it for the aesthetics. Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l = 0.25 # length of pendulum

# create a list of angles, convert to radians
theta_points_approx = [5.0,4.8,4.2,3.2,2.1,1.9,0.2,-1.2,-2.2,-3.1,-3.9,-4.6,-5.0]
theta_points_approx_rad = []
for ang in theta_points_approx:
    theta_points_approx_rad.append(ang*np.pi/180)

# create blank window for animation
fig = plt.figure()
axis = plt.axes()

pend_approx, = axis.plot([], [], lw=2)

#create a function to draw the background of our animations
def init():
    pend_approx.set_data([], [])
    return(pend_approx,)

# initialize empty sets for x and y coordinates
x_points_to_plot = []
y_points_to_plot = []

# animation function
def animate(theta):
    x = [0,l*np.sin(theta)]
    y = [0,-l*np.cos(theta)]
    pend_approx.set_data(x,y)
    return(pend_approx,)

# compile animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=theta_points_approx_rad, interval=40, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

This just outputs an empty plot. I have spent the evening watching YT videos and reading through animation examples trying to get this solved, but to no avail. I am not sure what to even try from here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It was not because I didn't have the show() function at the end. Even with show I still get an empty plot

Comment: You prepare the plot, but never `show` it.

Comment: That is not the issue. I have the exact same output even with the plt.show() at the end

Comment: Without `show`, I get no plot window at all.
With `show` inserted, I get a whirling pendulum (i.e. wrong data values), a follow-on problem.  What Python version are you on?  I'm using 3.8.3.

Comment: Python version 3.8.5 I also get the whirling pendulum when I compile in IDLE, but just a blank plot in Jupyter. So there is an issue with it being in Jupyter, but there also must be some confusion in how FuncAnimation works on my part. Because if it is feeding my theta values into my animate function like I thought it would, the pendulum wouldn't be so wild

Comment: When I correct your `animate` call to use the radians version instead of degrees, I get a very nice one-way pendulum (you iterate from +5 to -5 degrees, but then reset abruptly to +5).

Comment: ahhh incredible, what a silly oversight! My goal is still to get it running in the jupyter notebook though